# How to send response to a List of Groups and exclude some Connection Ids in SignalR Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

In AspNet.SignalR.Core, there was this method in `IHubConnectionContext` where you can send a response to a list of groups while excluding some Connection Ids i.e:

```
T Groups(IList<string> groupNames, params string[] excludeConnectionIds);
```

This would be called as:

```
Clients.Groups(groupNames, exconnectionIds).ReceiveCollaborationNotification(response);
```

Now I have migrated to `AspNetCore.SignalR.Core` and there is no such method that accepts both a list of group names and Connection Ids to be excluded. It does have the method mentioned below but this one only accepts one group name, not a list.

```
T GroupExcept(string groupName, IReadOnlyList<string> excludedConnectionIds);
```

How can I achieve what `T Groups(IList<string> groupNames, params string[] excludeConnectionIds` does in `AspNetCore.SignalR.Core`

Comment: Try what @Kiril suggested, in addition, you can get a selected `userList` on a dictionary and then upate the hub with that userList. You could have a look details on [official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups#adding-and-removing-users)

Answer (score 2):

In SignalR Core, you have this extension method:

```cs
public static T GroupExcept<T> (this Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.IHubClients<T> hubClients, string groupName, string excludedConnectionId1, string excludedConnectionId2, string excludedConnectionId3, string excludedConnectionId4, string excludedConnectionId5, string excludedConnectionId6, string excludedConnectionId7, string excludedConnectionId8);
```

You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.hubclientsextensions.groupexcept#microsoft-aspnetcore-signalr-hubclientsextensions-groupexcept-1(microsoft-aspnetcore-signalr-ihubclients((-0))-system-string-system-string-system-string-system-string-system-string-system-string-system-string-system-string-system-string)).

So to achieve what you want, you will need to use these [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.hubclientsextensions).